# Clearing markers from google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So far my program actively loads json data to the map as markers as the user pans and zooms. However I need to clear the existing markers each time this is done before the new markers are loaded in. This bit of code works and removes the markers but only when its attached to the button click DOM listener.

```
    var features = map.data.addGeoJson(data);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('removeBtn'), 'click', function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++)
                    map.data.remove(features[i]);
            });
```

Here is my code

```
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -98.35),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
       var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
         try{
           for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                    map.data.remove(features[i]); 
            }
            }catch(err){
                console.log("fail")
            }

         $.getJSON("/static/json/data.json", function(data) {
            var features = map.data.addGeoJson(data) {
          });
       });
     });       
   }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

GEOJSON data

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -84.375,
          36.31512514748051
        ]
      }
    }
   ]
  }
```

How can I approach this so that the 'idle' event listener clears existing markers before loading new ones?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks.. I removed all of the code unrelated to the issue.

Comment: You needed to add sample geoJSON and the map definition or a working code snippet, not remove code.

Comment: remove the var-keyword, otherwise `features` is only accessible inside the getJSON-callback

Comment: @Dr.Molle It worked! thank you so much!.... something so simple. I've spent my whole saturday trying to figure this out. I wish there was a way to give your comment best answer. Im relatively new to javascript and did not know you could declare things without var. Thanks again!

Comment: you can declare them without `var` , but basically it's a bad practice. But in this case it's already declared on top, you declare a new(private) variable in the geoJSON-callback instead of using the existing variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the features somewhere, a map knows the features.

Simply execute the following line to remove all features from a map:

```
(function(m){m.data.forEach(function(f){m.data.remove(f);});}(map))
```

Comment: Even better there are alot of answers to similar questions that talk about having to store the markers in an array so that you can access them to delete them. This is by far the easiest approach. Thank you!

Comment: I guess the other questions are not about the Data-Layer. When you create the Markers via `google.maps.Marker` you'll need to store them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the word `var` before `features` in the getJSON callback.

Delete that word.

Then, you'll be writing to the global `features` variable. Your for loop will be able to delete them.